# mutiple calls with same args to python function outputs different return values

Tags: python, function

This must be a quite basic misunderstanding from my part. I have a function that returns an interpolation function based on random values.

```
fct = create_interp_fct(x,y)
```

Now *fct* is a callable interpolation function. For example:

```
fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

returns

```
array([[ 0.75894378,  0.72761319, -0.23003647, -0.34790905, -0.51531125,
        -0.91211147]])
```

The function is defined roughly as follows:

```
def create_interp_fct(x,y):
    u,v = compute_some_random_values(x,y)
    return RegularGridInterpolator(u,v) #from from scipy.interpolate
```

The problem is that if I call *fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])* again I get a different output. So it is evident that the function gets redefined based on new random values. 
My question is: how can I use *fct* so that it doesn't get redefined each time I call it? Imagine the computation of *fct* is very expensive but to call it not. How can I "save" my currently computed function?  Or look at all the machine learning stuff from scikit for example(linear regression, etc...). If I call

```
 lr = lm.LinearRegression() # import sklearn.linear_model as lm
 lr.fit(M,n)
```

you cannot say me that every time I call lr.score(M,n), the linear regression gets recomputed?

Comment: Show us the code for `create_interp_fct()` too, please.

Comment: Check [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: if create_interp_fct has some random variables used, you should have a look at seeding the number generator so the same values will be output. random.seed would work if the random number generator in the function uses the random class. Otherwise look into the function itself to see what it is using for the random variables and seed it. Another option would be to use a dummy set for the random items but this is much more time consuming if there are many of them.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html

Comment: I guess, if the function is designed for returning a function with randomness, if you want to get rid of this randomness you'll have to redesign the function itself, but we can't help you without having it

Comment: Thank you so far! I will check it out. I am using np.random. But for my understanding: every time I call fct(args), the function gets redefined? This is what I don't understand. In my case, the computation of the function fct() is quite time consuming because it is based on some statistical data. @Nenri I don't want to get rid of randomness but rather be able to call a function multiple times without redefining / recomputing it from scratch every time.

Comment: So ye you should look at seeding as others adviced you, and you should maybe also give more informations about `create_interp_fct` 
anyway, you can find more infos about random seeding with numpy [there](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)

Comment: Try to create a minimal working example, i.e. minimal number of lines that will actually run for us, but which will recreate the error.  The confusing thing here is that most of the comments are focussed on the randomness, which happens in `create_interp_fct`, but your question **appears** to be saying that you get different results from consecutive calls to a *given* `fct` without re-calling `create_interp_fct` to get a new `fct`.  Perhaps you *are* refreshing `fct` without realizing it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of non-deterministic output from a **given** instance of `fct` is not replicated in the following example:

```
In [13]: paste                                                                                                                                                                      

import numpy
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator                                                                                                                      

def compute_some_random_values(shape):
    return [numpy.arange(extent) for extent in shape], numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, size=shape)

def create_interp_fct(shape):
    u,v = compute_some_random_values(shape)
    return RegularGridInterpolator(u,v) #from from scipy.interpolate

## -- End pasted text --


In [24]: fct = create_interp_fct([2,3,4,5,6,7])                                                                                                                                     

In [25]: fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])                                                                                                                                                         
Out[25]: array([0.24572906])

In [26]: fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])                                                                                                                                                         
Out[26]: array([0.24572906])

In [27]: fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])                                                                                                                                                         
Out[27]: array([0.24572906])

In [28]: fct([0,0,0,0,0,0])                                                                                                                                                         
Out[28]: array([0.24572906])
```

I suspect that, somewhere in your program logic, you have refreshed `fct` between calls, by calling `fct = create_interp_fct(...)` again without realizing it. That will naturally re-randomize things.